# How to change a Radgrid column value after binding?

Tags: sql, data-binding, telerik, radgrid

I have a Radgrid and I bind it with `SqlAdapter`. My problem is that I want to change just one column's value. Is that possible?

My column name is IsShadow and it binds true or false. I cannot change it. If value is false or true, I change column text appearence, not database update.

Code I've tried

```
foreach (Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem dataItem in gridShadow.MasterTableView.Items)
            {
                bool flag = Convert.ToBoolean(dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("IsShadow"));
                GridEditableItem editedItem = dataItem as GridEditableItem;
if (!flag)
                {
                    TableCell tableCell = editedItem["IsShadow"] = ???
                }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to replace true/false with another text or you need to change the edit column text.

Comment: I want to replace with another text, not update things. @JayeshGoyani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet and let me know if any concern.

```
// Normal Mode
if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
{
    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
    item["IsShadow"].Text = "Your new text";
}

// Edit Mode
if ((e.Item is GridEditableItem) && (e.Item.IsInEditMode))
{
    GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
    (editItem["IsShadow"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text = "Your new text";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a [GridTemplateColumn](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-column-types.html#template)

In the **ItemTemplate** you will check the value of IsShadow and display some text, but in **EditItemTemplate** you would probably need to just have a checkbox for true/false.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Is Shadow" UniqueName="TemplateColumn">
  <EditItemTemplate>    
    <asp:CheckBox id="editChkBox" runat="server"      
  Checked='<%# Bind("IsShadow") %>'>     
    </asp:CheckBox>
  </EditItemTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>      
    <asp:Lable id="lblIsShadow" runat="server"      
  Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsShadow")) == true ? "it is shadow" : "Not shadow" %>'>    
    </asp:CheckBox>   
  </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```